# How to extend search with SearchBar

Tags: objective-c, uisearchbar, nsrange

I want to search through an array with strings in it. Therefore i use a searchbar.
Here's my code:

```
for(NSString *string in itemsArray)
{
   NSRange nameRange = [string rangeOfString:text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
   if (nameRange.location != NSNotFound)
   {
      [filteredItemsArray addObject:string];
   }
}
```

It works great, but the problem is it just finds the string when I write it exactly the same way (except the case insensitivity).
But I would also like to find it even if the strings doesn't fit a 100%. For example when I search for 'Ralle Turner' it should also find the string with 'Ralle/Ralph Turner'.

Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split the search string into words, and then iterate through each word to find a match.

You can split the string using this code inside your loop

```
for(NSString *string in itemsArray)
{
    NSArray *words = [text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
    for (NSString *word in words)
    {
        NSRange nameRange = [string rangeOfString:word options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (nameRange.location != NSNotFound)
        {
           [filteredItemsArray addObject:string];
           break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so the words array is that one with my data inside?

Comment: @user3298017 No, the words array contains each one of the words in the search string. In your example it would contain 2 words: Ralle and Turner.

Comment: and what's the mystring for?

Comment: @user3298017 myString contains "Ralle Turner", it's the searchSring... I think it's the same as your `text` variable.

Comment: sorry I don't get it yet. Why do I loop through the words array then and not through the array where the data is in?

Comment: @user3298017 You loop through both arrays!!! I modified the code in my answer, check it and test it.

Comment: thanks a lot it works now. I'm sorry for being so dumb.

Comment: now i got another problem, all entries with 'ralle' or 'turner' are shown now, but how can i get 'ralle/ralph turner' on top of the list?

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the [levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) of two string to see if there is a potential match.
You can easily find some implementation on the web, for instance:

-[via NSString Category](https://gist.github.com/iloveitaly/1515464)

-[via a single method](https://gist.github.com/boratlibre/1593632)

Or use one the others [approximate string matching algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching)

Comment: I think this is a little to complicated for my purpose, but thanks for your help nonetheless.